# How can I use a 5" screen as a display for a Mac Mini? Is there a way to over-ride HDMI settings?

Tags: display, mac-mini

I purchased this 5" screen with 800x480 resolution:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B013JECYF2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013JECYF2)

The Elecrow screen is primarily designed for Raspberry pi, but I would also like to use it as a screen for my Mac Mini (running Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3) connected by HDMI.

I have programming experience and would be willing to experiment. An easy solution would be great (some driver to install?),  but some way to over-ride the settings of the HDMI  port to send a signal which the screen can understand also sounds like a potential solution.

Any ideas welcome, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working.

My HDMI cord wasn't fully plugged into the Elecrow screen.

Anyone who encounters this, it's totally possible.

This screen is so great (cheap, works and portable).

Comment: Sounds good! When you get a chance, mark this question as solved with your own answer. I know there's some weird delays with that, but when you get a chance.

Comment: confused why someone would downvote my answer to -1... I mean it is goofy, but could be useful information to someone :/

Comment: No idea, have an updoot.